# What level of schooling does it take for a native-Chinese speaker to understand CCTV news?

Tags: chinese, native-language

One of my iTalki teachers and I study [China Central Television (CCTV)](http://www.cctv.com/) news.  The hosts are noted for the extremely fast pronunciation (sometimes 280+ characters per minute) and their use of precise, technical vocabulary.

I still find watching CCTV news incredibly hard.  Another one of my iTalki teachers (a native-Chinese speaker) says he also finds it hard watching CCTV news, which makes me feel not so bad.  So...

**Question**: What level of schooling does it take for a native-Chinese speaker to understand CCTV news?

I'm guessing university-educated native-Chinese speakers find it easy enough, and primary-school-level native-Chinese speakers cannot understand it.  I'm thinking maybe Chinese high-school students, at some level, have homework or assignments where they need to watch and write about CCTV news.

(I like comparing my level with native speakers as it helps me find where I have unrealistic expectations and goals.  I'm trying to reach a level of Chinese in the same ballpark as a Chinese high-school student.)

Comment: I really like this question. By contrast, there is published research on the reading levels of various English-language newspapers, with some being notably higher than others.